# Align input elements inside two fieldsets

Tags: html, css

My sitsuation is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9fxvf5w2/10/ I need to get the input elements inside the fieldset elements to align with each other.

They align inside fieldset elements nicely, but I need them to align also with input elements inside the other fieldset.

html:

```
<ol>
            <fieldset >
                <legend>
                    kljjlkjlk
                </legend>

            <li><label>wertwsssssssssssssssertwert</label>
                <input />   
            </li>
            <li><label>asdasdasdas</label><input />
            </li>
                <li><label>xcvxcvxcvxc</label> <input />
            </li>


            </fieldset>
            <fieldset >
                <legend>
                    vxvcvcxv
                </legend>
                <li><label>wertwertwert</label>
                <input />   
            </li>
            <li><label>asdasdasdas</label><input />
            </li>
                <li><label>xcvxcvxcvxc</label> <input />
            </li>
            </fieldset>
        </ol>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
ol{
    display: table;
}

ol li{
    display: table-row;
}

ol li label,
ol li input{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for -1 and no comment -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, aligning 2 elements with same size is possible with css.

```
ol{

    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
}

ol li{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

ol li label,
ol li input{
    display: block;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    width:45%;
}
```

Comment: But I want to align elements that are inside fieldset elements. Not two elements..

Comment: maybe start with basic css courses? "form fieldset input" will select only input element inside fieldset element

Comment: So, I don't need to select them. Did you look at my jsFiddle?

Comment: I rewrote my question my you can understand it now better

Comment: go learn css and how to use developer tools in your browser. your li element is not stretching, thats why you can't align anything inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your goodwill and help that you tried to give. I'm sure you will improve with time.

Comment: Yes you linked my JsFiddle that shows the problem I have. I need the input element's inside fieldsets elements to be aligned, right now the bottom isnt alight with the top.

Comment: sorry, wrong link, not really familiar with js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9fxvf5w2/11/